# Add only the first value in my list of arrays

Tags: python, list

I have imported data from a file with the following numbers:
    [[1,2,3,4,5]
     [2,4,6,8,10]
     [3,6,9,12,15]]

I want to know how to add only the first, or second, or third, and so on value from each row. So, for example if I add the third number from each row, then my total will be 18 (3+6+9).

Also, how can I display these numbers in a one-dimensional array ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself already? If so, what didn't work? Did you get any error messages? We want to help, but this isn't a forum to get other people to do your work for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
l = [[1,2,3,4,5] ,[2,4,6,8,10],[3,6,9,12,15]]
```

If you want to print the sum individually,

```
print sum(l_item[0] for l_item in l)
```

Which would print:

```
6
```

If you want a list which in turn contains the results:

```
#Assuming all the sub lists have same length
num_rows = len(l)
num_cols = len(l[0])

sum_l = []

for i in range(0, num_cols):
    cur_sum = 0
    for j in range(0, num_rows):
            cur_sum += l[j][i]

    sum_l.append(cur_sum)

print sum_l
```

Which would print :

```
[6, 12, 18, 24, 30]
```

Hope this helps !

EDIT (Based on the further changes requested in the comments):

So basically, you want to divide the newly created list of numbers by number of lists or the number of rows. Here are few ways you can go about doing that.

Option 1: Do it within the for loop itself.

```
for i in range(0, num_cols):
    cur_sum = 0
    for j in range(0, num_rows):
            cur_sum += l[j][i]
    cur_sum /= num_rows
    sum_l.append(cur_sum)
```

OPTION 2: You can accomplish it using a list comprehension

```
sum_l1 = [ x/num_rows for x in sum_l]
```

OPTION 3: Using map function

```
sum_l1 = map(lambda x: x/num_rows, sum_l)
```

Comment: Great !! that's what I wanted. What if I want to average that result. So, what I am saying is divide each of those numbers by 3 because there are three sets of numbers. So, the result would print out to be 2,4,6,8,10.

Comment: @JACK: I have added the code changes which may be helpful in the edit. Hope its exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @Jack: If you're using Python 3.4 or later, you can use `statistics.mean` in place of `sum`. (For 3.1-3.3, you can also `pip install stats` and use that; it's the module that eventually became the stdlib `statistics`. There are also [lots of other statistics modules on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=statistics&submit=search), some of which work with versions back to Python 2.2 or even earlier.)

Answer (score 2):

```
 l = [[1,2,3,4,5] ,[2,4,6,8,10],[3,6,9,12,15]]

print sum(x[2] for x in l)
18
```

To put them in a list just use a list comprehension:

```
l2 = [x[2] for x in l]
print sum(l2),l2
18 [3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `numpy` library to do this for you. The `sum` function will add column-wise by default.

```
import numpy as np
l = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,4,6,8,10], [3,6,9,12,15]]

>>> np.array(l)
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12, 15]])

>>> sum(np.array(l))
array([ 6, 12, 18, 24, 30])
```

Answer (score 0):

This function doesn't check that your lists are at least length n, but I think you'll probably get the idea:

```
def add_nth_members(my_list, n):
    sum_list = [x[n-1] for x in my_list]
    print sum_list
    return sum(sum_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how to add only the first, or second, or third, and so on value from each row.

This looks like a job for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)!

The `zip` function will "transpose" your list of lists, so you get a list of first all the first values, then all the second values, and so on. It's probably easier to see it than to understand a description, so:

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,4,6,8,10], [3,6,9,12,15]]
>>> list(zip(*l))
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 4, 6), (3, 6, 9), (4, 8, 12), (5, 10, 15)]
```

That makes it dead easy to sum any particular index:

```
>>> zl = list(zip(*l))
>>> sum(zl[0])
6
>>> zum(zl[2])
18
```

… or all of them:

```
>>> [sum(i) for i in zip(*l)]
[6, 12, 18, 24, 30]
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
>>> list(map(sum, zip(*l)))
[6, 12, 18, 24, 30]
```

---

It's worth getting the hang of `zip`, because it makes a lot of hard problems easy.

For example, compare these two list comprehensions that do the same thing:

```
>>> [sum(i) for i in zip(*l)]
[6, 12, 18, 24, 30]
>>> [sum(i[n] for i in l) for n in range(len(l[0]))]
[6, 12, 18, 24, 30]
```

Besides being a lot more compact and readable, and harder to get wrong, the `zip` version also lets you do the right thing if the lists are all different lengths. Well, "the right thing" is different for different cases, but generally, either you want to stop when the shortest is exhausted, or "fill in" the shortest ones, not get a mysterious exception that you don't understand. Compare:

```
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
>>> [sum(i) for i in zip(*l)]
[5, 7]
>>> import itertools
>>> [sum(i) for i in zip_longest(*l, fillvalue=0)]
[5, 7, 3]
>>> [sum(i[n] for i in l) for n in range(len(l[0]))]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
IndexError: list index out of range
```